# Ethernet not working, wireless is

Tags: router, windows-10, ethernet, active-directory

Since I put my computer on my domain at home (AD/DS) and set the security of my wireless access point to RADIUS with NPS, I started experiencing issues.

When my laptop is connected via WLAN, it works fine.

When I plug in a cable, it works for 10 minutes, but after that it doesn't. When I click the "Troubleshoot" button in Windows, it solves it, and tells me there was a problem with the default gateway. (About 10 minutes after solving this, it happends again) That gateway is the same on wireless as on ethernet (pfSense firewall).

The operating system of my laptop and the other computers is Windows 10 (Education). The server has Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter (via DreamSpark).

When I add another computer to the domain, that computer also starts experiencing those issues.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your operating system (vital information).

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, I just added the operating system (Windows), thank you for your response.